# How to get template class template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class and want to know, how to get template class variable type when it is used as a template parameter of function.
I tried to do the following

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class foo
{
};

template <typename templateClass>
void f()
{
    if (is_same<typename templateClass::T, int>::value)
        cout << "int";
    else if (is_same<typename templateClass::T, double>::value)
        cout << "double";
    else
        cout << "Unknown type";
}

int main()
{
    f<foo<double>>();

    return 0;
}
```

This code does not compile, because `no type named 'T' in 'foo<double>'`.
Then I changed it a little bit:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class foo
{
public:
    using Type = T; //can't write : using T = T;
};

template <typename templateClass>
void f()
{
    if (is_same<typename templateClass::Type, int>::value)
        cout << "int";
    else if (is_same<typename templateClass::Type, double>::value)
        cout << "double";
    else
        cout << "Unknown type";
}

int main()
{
    f<foo<double>>();

    return 0;
}
```

Now it works fine, but I had to rename template parameter. Can I get template parameter value without renaming it with `using`?

Comment: You're not renaming `T`, you're renaming `double`

Comment: How about `f<std::string>()`, i.e. a typo not generated from `foo`? What is the actual problem you want to solve?

Comment: "*Can I get template parameter value without renaming it with using?*" The simple answer is No.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create traits to extract that information without changing originel types.

```
template <typename T>
struct template_parameter;

template <template <typename ...> class C, typename T>
struct template_parameter<C<T>>
{
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T>
using template_parameter_t = typename template_parameter<T>::type;
```

and then

```
template <typename templateClass>
void f()
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<template_parameter_t<templateClass>, int>)
        std::cout << "int";
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<template_parameter_t<templateClass>, double>)
        std::cout << "double";
    else
        std::cout << "Unknown type";
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60547eeda198303b)

Comment: HI, @Jarod42, I don't know How to call/use your code. would you mind share the full code....

Comment: @Mark: typo fixed (`_v` and `::value`) and Demo added.